# Android: Efficient way to grab image from camera and send it to server

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I need my App to take a photo using the camera, show it in my Activities `ImageView`, and then sent it to a server using an HttpClient. So far, so good. Unfortunately, I stumbled upon the well described `MemoryOutOfBoundsException`. So I want to compress my image using JPG or PNG.

Now - after some excessive googling - do I get this right:

a) The camera will always output an uncompressed `Bitmap`, which is directly written to the file system. I.e. like this:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
this.imageTempFile = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myTempFileName"); // write the camera output to a tmpFile
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(this.imageTempFile)); // link the tmpFile to a member for convenience later on
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

So there is no way to resize / compress it right away?

b) If I want to display an image in a `ImageView`, I need to pass a Bitmap to it using `ImageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)`. So showing the result is extremely memory consuming...!?

c) If I want to alter the Bitmap (resize / compress), I need to read it from this file into memory using a `BitmapFactory`

d) Now I can resize the Bitmap using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`

e) But if I want to compress the image, I need to write it back to the file system using an `OutputStream` via `Bitmap.compress()`...

f) So for the task of taking an image, resizing it, showing it, and then sending it to a server, I need to actually write it to a file, then read it, then write it to a file again, then read it - and then send it? WTF? I there no easier way?

PS: Here's my code for b) to e):

```
// c) read the Bitmap from file
Bitmap bitmap;
BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(this.imageTempFile.getAbsolutePath(), bitmapOptions);

// d) do some resizing
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) mywidth, (int) myheight, true);

// e) compress
OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(50);

this.imageTempFile.delete();

File file = new File(this.imageTempFile.getAbsolutePath());

try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// NOW we could read it again from the file to send it afterwards...
Bitmap newBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(this.imageTempFile.getAbsolutePath(), bitmapOptions);
```